# How to mark a ruby package as a beta or developer release

Tags: ruby, rubygems, versioning

Is there a way to mark or version a ruby package, specifically a rubygem, as a developer or beta release?

In the Perl world, there is a [widely respected convention](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodstyle.html#Version-numbering) of the underscore-separated minuscule number indicating a developer release.  That is, 1.23_01 is a dev release following ordinary release 1.23, and the [main Perl packaging software](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN/lib/CPAN.pm#The_four_CPAN%3a%3a%2a_Classes%3a_Author,_Bundle,_Module,_Distribution) and [community distribution site](http://www.cpan.org/modules/04pause.html#developerreleases) know this.  Is there a similar practice for ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rubygems supports the notion of [prerelease gems](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#prerelease-gems). To mark a gem version as a prerelease you just have to include at least one letter in the version number (for example `1.0.a`, `1.0.beta1`, `1.0.dev1`).

Rubygems version numbers must match this regular expression: `[0-9]+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*`, thus hyphens or underscores are not allowed.

Comment: @pilcrow Yes, you can find it in `rubygems/version.rb`, it's the constant `VERSION_PATTERN` (rubygems 1.8.23).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the project, but I've seen [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) used quite often.